# How to update object using react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update my object when the user clicks on the button, append to array element id. But when I adding data to array it overrides all object without saving previous data. I passed prevState callback but it doesn't work.

```
const [filteredObject, setFilter] = useState({destinations:[],season:[],difficulty:[],price:'',is_exclusive:'',duration:''});

if (e.currentTarget.name==='destinations') {
   setFilter(prevState=>({...prevState, destinations:[ ...prevState.destinations, e.currentTarget.id]}))
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `destinations:[ e.currentTarget.id]`, you are actually overriding the existing array.

You need to do this,

```
setFilter( prevState => ({
   ...prevState, 
   destinations:[ ...prevState.destinations, e.currentTarget.id ]
}))
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gxz5l2)

Comment: @ravibagul91 I have tried already like you, but it throws an error. Please check above

Comment: @YerlanYeszhanov, Post the complete function and the element from that function gets called.

Comment: @YerlanYeszhanov, check this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gxz5l2), this may help you.